# Accessing the file created in internal storage

Tags: java, android

I decided to save a file using internal storage into a folder. My code is:

```
File dir = new File (getFilesDir(), "myFolder");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "myData.txt");

try {
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
    pw.println("Hi");
    pw.println("Hello");
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    f.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}   
tv.append("\n\nFile written to "+file);
```

The directory shown is data/data/packageName/file/myFolder/myData.txt
However, I wanted to check whether the file contains the strings inputted but i can't seem to find where the created file is. I tried to output the contents of the file but i failed. I know this sounds ridiculous. All i wanna do is to check the contents and also know whether a file is created or not. Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code at the end,

```
try {
        File file = new File(dir, "myData.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

        while(sc.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a input stream from the file and read line by line.

```
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(new File(getFilesDir()+"/myFolder/"+"myData.txt"));
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
while (dis.available() != 0) {
    System.out.println(dis.readLine());
}
```

Comment: ok, thank you! is there a way to manually locate and check the contents of the file created?